# How to reference columns in a dataframe from a list object

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm developing a bit of code that will work on a file which changes each year. Each year that passes, a new column will be added which references that year is added.

I have a list of years created with the below code:

```
yearList = []
    for i in range(2010, now.year):
        yearList(str(i))
```

So for now, the yearList contains the string values of 2010-2018 which reflects the columns in my file.

However, next year, this array will contain 2019 as will my file.

I want to reorder some columns in my dataframe and have all the years at the end. Previously I was doing something like this:

```
dfComboC = dfComboC[['columnX', 'columnY', 'columnZ', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', 
    '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018']]
```

Obviously the above will be out of date in 2020, so I wanted to use the yearList like such:

```
dfComboC = dfComboC[['columnX', 'columnY', 'columnZ', yearList]]
```

As expected, this didn't work. Does anyone know of a way to make it work?

Comment: You also could use list comprehension like this: yearList = [x for x in range(2010, now.year)]

Comment: @AndreasHofmann thanks, wasn't aware of that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yearList` is a list object on it's own, and not a name of a single column.

Try:

```
dfComboC = dfComboC[['columnX', 'columnY', 'columnZ'] + yearList]
```

Comment: This works perfect, I'll accept it as the answer shortly

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ["a","b","c"]
b = ["d","e","f"]

c = a+b

print(c)
```

wil give :

['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

does that help you?